# Call variable with string c# console application

Tags: c#, console-application

Is there a way so that if you have a string containing the name of a defined variable, you can call that variable. For example:

```
string Hello = "Hello";
Console.WriteLine("What is the name if the variable?");
userInput = Console.ReadLine();
userInput.Replace('Hello', 'Hi'); <---//This would replace the value of Hello not the value of userInput
```

How would I Let the user input the variable name then use the string to call that variable?

Comment: What is the practical value of this question?

Comment: Variables are not "called", users dont/cant name variables.  You can however assign user input to vars so that `string greeting` is "Hi:, "Hello" or :"bon jour" depending on what they enter

Comment: You **can** use reflection to do this, but you really have to ask yourself *why* you're doing it.

Comment: you're mixing user interaction with low-level language features here, and that never ends well. If you need to define a discrete set of menu options or something similar, do that, either using some map or enumeration, but keep this separate from low-level stuff like assigning values to variables. they are not conceptually related.

Answer (score 2):

While this isn't directly possible in C#, you can achieve this effect by using a Dictionary with a string as a key and a generic type as a value. There's no context, but probably a better way to achieve what you want without doing this sort of variable referencing.

**Edit**: [Here is the MSDN documentation for a Dictionary object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1), which may be of some insight on operations you can perform with the type.

Here's an example snippet using a dictionary to achieve the code you provided in your question. Simply add the name of the variable and the initial value of the variable to the dictionary (via `vars.Add(key, value)` method, or `vars["UniqueKeyName"] = value;`). In my example, users will only be able to modify keys that already exist in the program before it begins.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    Dictionary<string, object> vars = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    vars.Add("Hello", "Hello");
    vars.Add("KeyTwo", 4);
    vars.Add("FloatVal", 8.6f);
    Console.WriteLine("What is the name of the variable?");
    string varname = Console.ReadLine();
    if (vars.ContainsKey(varname))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What is the new value to set that variable to?");
        Type t = vars[varname].GetType();
        try
        {
            dynamic newval = Convert.ChangeType(Console.ReadLine(), t);
            vars[varname] = newval;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is now {1}", varname, vars[varname]);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("That variable does not exist.");
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

If you can guarantee that you want to always use string variables, then you don't need the complication I made using an `object` as the value of the dictionary, you can simply define the dictionary as `Dictionary<string, string> vals = new Dictionary<string, string>()`, change the `dynamic` line to `string newval = Console.ReadLine();`. The point of the try/catch and Convert.ChangeType is if you want to use variables of different types, this will try to convert the input received from the console (which is a string) and convert it to the type of the variable it expects from the dictionary for the specified key. For instance, asking for the `Hello` variable, will convert the dynamic variable to a string, asking for the `FloatVal` variable will attempt to convert the input to a float. If the value entered is not the type it expects, it will throw an exception and print error message.

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to answer this question! See my comment on Alex's answer.

Comment: No problem, I've edited my response to give an example.

Answer (score 1):

The practical merit of your question is unclear. For the purpose you have described, you may use `Dictionary` object (key-value like `<string, string>`) and operate on it: for example, if User provides the `Key`, then you can modify the `Value` or compose a string containing that `Value`, pertinent to your business logic.

Following is a sample use of `Dictionary` object pertinent to the similar use-case in Console app:

```
Dictionary<string, string> names = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"1", "John"},
    {"2", "Anna"},
    {"3", "Gary"},
    {"4", "Jacob"},
    {"5", "Jennifer"}
};

Console.WriteLine("What is your ID?");
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
if (names.Keys.Contains(userInput))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello " + names[userInput] + "! Nice to see you online.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, this is not a valid ID. Bye.");
}
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please add an example of how to use a Dictionary? The OP is my son. He's just getting into programming and this is his first Stack Overflow question. He's a smart kid and I'm sure he'll figure it out now that you've pointed him in the right direction. He's familiar with the concept of a dictionary from Python but static typing adds a new twist. If you can provide any more direction I promise your effort will not go to waste. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. As per your request, please refer to my extended answer w/sample use-case pertinent to Dictionary object. Best regards,